# is it safe to write a new application in angularjs 1.2?

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, future

We want to convert our web app to angularjs, the problem is we need to support IE8 so only option is to stick with angularjs version 1.2. The question is it safe to go with this version? As 1.3 is already out and soon version 2.0 will be there too, so in near future (like 8-12 months) if we dropped IE8 support and then want to migrate to 1.3 or even 2 how much effort it will be?

Answer (score 1):

Migration from Angular 1.2 to 1.3 is far more easier as compared to moving to Angular 2.0

There is even a [migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) to migrate from 1.2 to 1.3. So migrating would be possible to 1.3 or 1.4 or 1.x.

There is a bit of paradigm shift when it comes to Angular 2.0. The migration path is still not clear and we even don't know whether one is possible.

**Update**: This [video from ngconf 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pai1ZdFI2dg), gives some useful insight into how build today with 1.3, that makes transition easy.